# Efficient way to divide a sequence of datetimes into lists of "sequential" datetimes?

Tags: python, datetime

Let's say that "sequential" datetimes are datetimes within a certain interval of time (i.e. thirty minutes) of each other; non-sequential datetimes are datetimes that are a longer period of time than that from each other.

Given an input consisting of a list of datetimes (as strings), I'd like to derive a list of lists of sequential datetimes. My solution is as follows, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it:

```
list_of_datetime_strings: ['2016-02-26 10:30:00', '2016-02-26 11:00:00', 
'2016-02-25 11:30:00', '2016-02-25 12:00:00', '2016-02-25 12:30:00', 
'2016-02-26 12:30:00']

def find_datetime_sequences(list_of_datetime_strings, increment_in_minutes = 30):
    if not list_of_datetime_strings:
        return

    str_to_datetime = lambda cur_datetime: datetime.strptime(cur_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    list__datetimes_sorted = sorted([str_to_datetime(cur_datetime) for cur_datetime in list_of_datetime_strings])

    list_of_datetime_lists = [[list__datetimes_sorted[0]]]

    for cur_datetime in list__datetimes_sorted[1:]:
        time_difference = (cur_datetime - list_of_datetime_lists[-1][-1]).seconds / 60            

        if time_difference == increment_in_minutes:
            list_of_datetime_lists[-1].append(cur_datetime)
        else:
            list_of_datetime_lists.append([cur_datetime])

    return list_of_datetime_lists

find_datetime_sequences(list_of_datetime_strings)
```

Output:

```
list_of_datetime_lists: [[datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 25, 11, 30), 
     datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 25, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 25, 12, 30)], 
    [datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 26, 10, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 26, 11, 0)], 
    [datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 26, 12, 30)]]
```

Is there a better way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Can you fix the formatting?  Also your current code sample doesn't actually have any output as nothing is ever called.  That said, I think I would do something similar, only I might use the bisect library in python to get logarithmic performance for finding sequential dates.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Comment: I think sorting and then splitting is the most efficient way: O(nlogn+n).

Comment: Sorting, then binary search is asymptotically equal by in practice might be faster.  Especially if you are querying multiple times on a single sorted list.

Comment: @GarrettR - 1. Which aspect of the formatting needs to be fixed? 2. It's implicit that the function is going to be called, and it's obvious how to do this, so the missing code is pretty redundant, but alright, I'll go ahead and do that. 3. Thanks for the suggested solution. Would be cool if you can post code for it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a better way of making `datetime` objects from strings or sorting them. But I think the rest can be improved (readability-wise if nothing else) by using a generator instead of a regular function.

```
def sequencify(sorted_datetimes, increment_in_minutes=30):
    """Take a sorted list of datetime objects. Yield sequences as lists."""
    if not sorted_datetimes:
        return

    first, *rest = sorted_datetimes
    # python 2: first, rest = sorted_datetimes[0], sorted_datetimes[1:]
    sequence = [first]
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=increment_in_minutes)
    while rest:
        first, *rest = rest
        if first - sequence[-1] > delta:
            yield sequence
            sequence = [first]
        else:
            sequence.append(first)
    yield sequence
```

An alternative version which uses index-based approach, similar to what @SimeonVisser did:

```
def sequencify(sorted_datetimes, increment_in_minutes=30):
    """Take a sorted list of datetime objects. Yield sequences as lists."""
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=increment_in_minutes)
    start = 0
    for i in range(start, len(sorted_datetimes) - 1):
        if sorted_datetimes[i+1] - sorted_datetimes[i] > delta:
            yield sorted_datetimes[start:i+1]
            start = i + 1
    if sorted_datetimes:
        yield sorted_datetimes[start:]
```

Either way, minimal change is required of the caller: just add a `list()`:

```
strings = [
    '2016-02-26 10:30:00',
    '2016-02-26 11:00:00',
    '2016-02-25 11:30:00',
    '2016-02-25 12:00:00',
    '2016-02-25 12:30:00',
    '2016-02-26 12:30:00'
]
sorted_datetimes = sorted(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                          for s in strings)
print(list(sequencify(sorted_datetimes)))  # explicit conversion to list
```

Output:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 25, 11, 30),
  datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 25, 12, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 25, 12, 30)],
 [datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 26, 10, 30),
  datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 26, 11, 0)],
 [datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 26, 12, 30)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is essentially the same approach but it may be easier to maintain:

```
import datetime

strings = [
    '2016-02-26 10:30:00',
    '2016-02-26 11:00:00',
    '2016-02-25 11:30:00',
    '2016-02-25 12:00:00',
    '2016-02-25 12:30:00',
    '2016-02-26 12:30:00',
]

def find_datetime_sequences(strings, increment_in_minutes=30):
    if not strings:
        return

    dates = sorted([
        datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        for s in strings
    ])

    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=increment_in_minutes)
    start = 0
    n_items = len(dates)
    cuts = []
    for index in range(n_items):
        next_index = index + 1
        if next_index == n_items and start != next_index:
            cuts.append((start, next_index))
        elif dates[next_index] - dates[index] != delta:
            cuts.append((start, next_index))
            start = next_index
    return [dates[i:j] for i, j in cuts]
```

This part here is to detect when a difference between two dates is not 30 minutes and that we need to cut there:

```
elif dates[next_index] - dates[index] != delta:
    cuts.append((start, next_index))
    start = next_index
```

This part here is there to make sure that, if there is a datetime at the end that needs to go in a group of its own, that we do that:

```
if next_index == n_items and start != next_index:
    cuts.append((start, next_index))
```